# TPH - how to satisfy FK constraint when FK is on derived class?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design, ef-code-first

Let's say I have TPH for abstract class `Person`.  Then I have `Girl` and `Boy` derived from this class.  `Girl` has a relationship with `FavoriteMakeup` that `Boy` does not have.  How do I satisfy the FK constraint on `Makeup` when inserting a `Boy` record?  Or is TPH incompatible with FKs limited to derived types?

---

<sub>TPH: Table Per Hierarchy

FK: Foreign Key</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two separate aspects here. Let's examine both of them.

The first is if a foreign key can have or not null values in a Relational DBMS. In general this is allowed: you can have both a foreign key constraint and a not null constraint or a foreign key constraint while the attribute can be, at the same time, nullable. This is because the two constraints are usually considered independent. For instance, a NULL value could have the meaning that the value is unknown for a particular object.

The second aspect is related to modeling: usually, in cases like your example, while you *can* use the “Table per Hierarchy” approach, this is not considered a good modeling practice: you should use the “Table per Type” (or TPT to use the jargon of Microsoft documentation) approach, since all the Girl entities have an association with the other entities Makeup, while the entities Boy do not have this association, and this fact is part of the meaning of the entity, not some special case for some entity (like an unknown value).

Comment: I'm so scared of TPT though because of the code repetition.  Either I start repeating code (in model definitions), or muddy up my business logic.  Is there a "right" way or is this philosophical?

Comment: In the database world, actually the TPT approach is used a lot for subclasses, you can find this in all database books. While do you say that you are repeating code? If your application level is written in a object-relational mapping framework, the usual inheritance mechanism does not introduce significant code duplication.

Comment: I mean if we take a look at the implications of TPT, I'll have three or four `Payment` tables, each sharing ~50-70% column definitions. This seems a bit less ideal than enforcing data relations with business logic in one place... but I don't know.

Comment: In the table for type the only common column is the foreign key towards the table representing the superclass. No other common attribute in needed.